# HTML 5 independent Scrolling for perspective illusion

Tags: html, scroll

Is there some sample HTML code that establishes the following effect:

There is a foreground layer, containing text and images. Then there is a background layer, displaying an image,

When the user scrolls the page, the foreground scrolls at regular speed, but the background with a lower speed.

This would create a Flintstones-like faux perspective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "faux perspective" you're talking about is called [parallax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax).

There are a number of demos available online

- http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html
- http://dev.jonraasch.com/scrolling-parallax/examples/scrolling-parallax

I would suggest using a background image on `body` with `background-attachment: fixed` and then set a short timer to check the page scroll length.

On every update of the timer, detect the scroll length, and multiply it by a modifier (say 0.1), set this new value as the `background-position`:

```
$body = $('body');

function parallax()
{
  var pageOffsetX, pageOffsetY, modifiedOffsetX, modifiedOffsetY;

  pageOffsetX = ...//get the offset
  pageOffsetY = ...//get the offset
  modifiedOffsetX = pageOffsetX * 0.1;
  modifiedOffsetY = pageOffsetY * 0.1;

  $body.css('background-position', modifiedOffsetX + 'px ' + modifiedOffsetY + 'px');
  setTimeout(parallax, 100);
}

parallax();
```

The modifier is how much the background should move for every px the user scrolls. You may need to adjust the offsets if your background shouldn't repeat, and you may need to negate the offset depending on how you get the pageOffset values.

Adjusting the timeout will change the responsiveness of the background. You may be able to capture a mouse scroll event, but you'll also have to check if a user has jumped down the page via a link, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, for both the URLs as well as the core code!

Answer (score 1):

The way I would accomplish this is first by setting `background: fixed` for the page, and then constantly polling the page to determine whether the `window.pageYOffset` value has changed [1].  If it has changed, you can then move the background image up or down by (half|one third|one fourth|whatever) that amount, to mimic the effect you're talking about.

I'm not going to try to code this up, but I would be very interested to see your result.

[1] Note: Do NOT do this by attaching an event to the pagescroll event, as doing so can [seriously screw up most browsers](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/), as twitter learned the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

These are not the droids you are looking for, but the final effect is very similar: http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

> These layers move in response to the mouse, and, depending on their dimensions (and options for layer initialisation), they move by different amounts, in a parallaxy kind of way.

You may want to play around with that and adjust it so that the parallax effect is only horizontal (set the option `xparallax:false`).